# if I have 2 signals that are similar how will their cross correlation will look like?

Tags: correlation

I need to compare between 2 signals that both of them are different notes of the same musical instrument, so I thought maybe I can do it by Cross-Correlation but I dont really understand how to do it and how does it work?

Comment: Maybe you should look in the frequency domain instead of the time domain.

Answer (score 1):

For something like a saxophone I would think that even playing the same note two times by the same player, there will be significant differences on a wavform level. Depending on your application, I would think that somehow analyzing for «pitch» and «timbre», perhaps «envelope» are more useful.

Did you try commercial tools for altering pitch of recorded instruments?